# Xamarin - using xbuild to build a project with xamarin componenet added

Tags: xamarin, json.net, xbuild

Xbuild [Xamarin Studio] on mac os x

I am trying to build a solution & (Visual studio project file) csproj using xbuild.
This solution holds a project - which is not the startup project and which has a reference to Newtonsoft [Added using xamarin component] Please note the component is marked as "Included in this Project."

The solution and the project build fine in Xamarin, however on deleting the entire solution and their files. Now using team city to download the project and then use Xbuild to build the same the solution and the project both fail wih the following error message :

I have appended a  snapshot of the error message

```
    [18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Evidence/EvidenceNotRequired.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Evidence/PhotoEvidence.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Evidence/TextEvidence.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/BoundedQuestion.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/ExtendedInfoQuestion.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/InfoItem.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/MultiResponseQuestion.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/Question.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

[18:01:48]  [Step 3/4] ../../../../NESQuestionFramework/NESQuestionFramework/Model/Questions/QuestionSet.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Xbuild does try and ValidateAndroidPackage path however it cannot locate the  Newtonsoft.Json package.

```
        Target _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:

            GetAndroidPackageName Task

              ManifestFile: 

              AssemblyName: NESQuestionFramework

              PackageName: NESQuestionFramework.NESQuestionFramework

        Target _AndroidResolveAssemblyReferences:
```

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Newtonsoft.Json' not resolved

```
            For searchpath {CandidateAssemblyFiles}

            Warning: {CandidateAssemblyFiles} not supported currently

            For searchpath {HintPathFromItem}

            Considered ../../Components/json.net-4.5.11/lib/android/Newtonsoft.Json.dll, but it does not exist.

            For searchpath {TargetFrameworkDirectory}

            Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3, assembly named 'Newtonsoft.Json' not found.

            Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0, assembly named 'Newtonsoft.Json' not found.

            Considered target framework dir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/, assembly named 'Newtonsoft.Json' not found.

            For searchpath {PkgConfig}

            Considered Newtonsoft.Json, but could not find in any pkg-config files.

            For searchpath {GAC}

            Considered Newtonsoft.Json, but could not find in the GAC.

            For searchpath {RawFileName}

            Considered '/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b998b8d1d0b0ff61/NESTouch/NESTouch.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/Newtonsoft.Json' as a file, but the file does not exist

            For searchpath bin/Debug/

            Considered '/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b998b8d1d0b0ff61/NESTouch/NESTouch.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json' as a file, but the file does not exist

            Considered '/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b998b8d1d0b0ff61/NESTouch/NESTouch.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.exe' as a file, but the file does not exist

            Considered '/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b998b8d1d0b0ff61/NESTouch/NESTouch.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/NESQuestionFramework.Android/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' as a file, but the file does not exist
```

What would be the correct approach to sort out this problem.
Currently I am forcing the developers to log onto the server and manually build the solution using xamarin studio [which I believe does download Newtonsoft] and run it every subsequent time using xbuild.
Many thanks for your time

Rajesh

Comment: According to the logs, it's trign to find Newtosoft.dll at ../../Components/json.net-4.5.11/lib/android/Newtonsoft.Json.dll, so are sure that the file exist by this path?

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem, updated to json.net 6.0.2 and now this happens when I try to build the whole solution. If I build each project individually it works. Before I was on 6.0.1-beta1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but we are using json.net (newtonsoft) from nuget
which allows to easily run nuget restore on the solution.

as a work around you can run mdtool from the xamarin studio which worked fine (has some limitations)